# (Visual Basic 2010)What is causing my program to hang after multiple uses?

Tags: vb.net

Because I am not sure what is causing it, I have to copy and paste all the code, sorry if thats against the rules. This program is written in Visual Basic 2010 and what it should do is use cmd to operate Robocopy then display the results in real time. It does this, but hangs after a few uses, I'm new to this coding and am not too sure how to handle threads so it could be that but I have no idea how to fix it anyway.

If someone could help me I'd be very grateful :)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Results As String
Private Delegate Sub delUpdate()
Private Finished As New delUpdate(AddressOf UpdateText)
Dim button_click As Integer = 0
Dim myProcess As New Process
Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

Dim Folder_TBC As String
Dim Folder_DES As String
Dim RoboCommand As String

Private Sub UpdateText()
    ' TextBox_CMDout.Text = Results
    TextBox_CMDout.AppendText(System.Environment.NewLine() & Results)
    TextBox_CMDout.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If button_click = 0 Then
        RoboCommand = Chr(34) + TextBox_FolderTBC.Text + Chr(34) + " " + Chr(34) + TextBox_FolderDes.Text + Chr(34) + " "

        If CheckBox_ISF.Checked = True Then RoboCommand = RoboCommand + "/S "
        If CheckBox_MUT.Checked = True Then RoboCommand = RoboCommand + "/MT "
        If CheckBox_MOV.Checked = True Then RoboCommand = RoboCommand + "/Move "

        opencmd()
        button_click += 1
    End If
    Dim CMDThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf CMDAutomate)
    CMDThread.Start()





End Sub

Private Sub opencmd()
    StartInfo.FileName = "cmd" 'starts cmd window
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 'required to redirect
    StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 'creates no cmd window
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    myProcess.StartInfo = StartInfo
    myProcess.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub CMDAutomate()
    'Dim SR As System.IO.StreamReader = myprocess.StandardOutput
    'Dim SW As System.IO.StreamWriter = myprocess.StandardInput
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("robocopy " & Folder_TBC & Folder_DES)
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine())

    ' SW.WriteLine("exit") 'exits command prompt window
    While myProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream = False
        Results = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
        Invoke(Finished)
    End While
    'Results = SR.ReadToEnd 'returns results of the command window
    'SW.Close()
    'SR.Close()
    'invokes Finished delegate, which updates textbox with the results text
    Application.ExitThread()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox_FolderTBC.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox_FolderDes.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Application.ExitThread()
    Application.Exit()
    End
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: "I'm new to this coding and am not too sure how to handle threads" - OK, you've picked an advanced topic to start with!  What's with all the conmmented out code?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat Well I'm only new to threads Visual Basic. I have been coding little things for over a year now and am just getting into them. The comments are to help remind me what some things do until I remember off by heart.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the TextBox_CMDout text when a next click is processed, you are concatenating all output again and again

Next I think your solution is FAR too complicated for what you want to do.

Try this (and fill in the right parameters from your textboxes), more is NOT NEEDED and avoids topics as "When do you EXIT from the CMD command?" and similar.

```
   Dim myProcess As New Process()
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Robocopy"
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/?"
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    myProcess.Start()
    TextBox_CMDout.Text = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
    myProcess.Close()
```

Comment: I would also add a blank between the foldernames in the command, but it seems to work without, can't guess why.